# NodeJS - Can't attach Client Certificate for Testing with Mocha/Chai-Http

Tags: node.js, authentication, certificate, mocha.js, chai-http

I'm checking the client certificate on my login endpoint. Testing with Postman etc. all works just fine, but I can't get it running with my mocha/chai-http unit tests.

```
const ca = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', process.env.SERVER_CERT_FILE));
const cert = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', process.env.CLIENT_CERT_FILE));
const key = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', process.env.CLIENT_KEY_FILE));

describe('POST /login', () => {
        it('validates the certificate', (done) => {
            chai.request(app)
                .post('/api/login')
                .ca(ca)
                .key(key)
                .cert(cert)
                .send(userData)
                .end((err: Error, res: any) => {
                    /* checks */
                    done();
                });
        });
```

I can't even get the `req.socket.getPeerCertificate()` in that way. Does anybody know how this would work?

My login controller method:

```
login = (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    if (!req.client.authorized) {
        sendJSONResponse(res, 'Missing or invalid client certificate', 401);
        return;
    }
    /* .... */
 }
```

My server options

```
const options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SERVER_KEY_FILE),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SERVER_CERT_FILE),
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        ca: [
            fs.readFileSync(process.env.SERVER_CERT_FILE)
        ]
    };
    https.createServer(options, this.app).listen(port, () => {
        /*...*/;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use module.exports on the https listener object. I had the same exact issue, and solved by making below change. Hope this helps.

```js
module.exports = https.createServer(options, app)
  .listen(443, function () {
    console.log('HTTPS App listening on port 443! Go to https://localhost:443/')
  })
```

Comment: Hi @user11477381, could you try to explain what your solution does?